# DataTable.AcceptChanges in loop -> ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable

I get data from a SQLite DB (which contains several tables) and load them into a dataGridView in tabs.
I would like to initialize each row status (-> "Unchanged") of each table by using the AcceptChanges() function of a DataTable object in a loop, but I meet the following error message :

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll

Rem. 0 : The exception occurred at a "random" nth table (of 16) in the loop. In my case, it was first at the 9nth table, then after adding new code lines it is actually at the 5th table.

Rem. 1 : I have also checked that all DataTable object have their own and unique TableName.

```
List<String> tableList = SQLITE.getDBElement(SQLITE.getCnx(SQLITE.path), "table");

foreach (String name in tableList)
    {
        // Creating tab and data gridview
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(name);
        tabPage.Name = name;
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
        tabPage.AutoScroll = true;

        DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView.Name = name;
        dataGridView.AutoSize = true;
        tabPage.Controls.Add(dataGridView);

        // Get table datas
        DataTable table = SQLITE.getTableContent_v2(SQLITE.getCnx(SQLITE.path), name);
        dataGridView.DataSource = table;

        // Add row change event
        table.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Table_RowChanged);

        // Init lines status
        table.AcceptChanges(); //-> throw an exception after several loops

        }
```

Rem. 2 : without the last line "table.AcceptChanges();", there is no error (all tabs with their dataGridView are loaded with data.

Rem. 3 : If I manually do a "table.AcceptChanges();" via a button click event, it works fine for all tables loaded.

Comment: Did you check to see if the table was null or the name of the table to see if is valid.  You may get tables from the schema query that you do not have permission to read (like System tables).

Comment: Why do you need `AcceptChanges` at all? What does `getTableContent_v2` return, a table with rows where some `DataRow.DataRowState` are not `Unchanged`? Otherwise omit this line, it just causes a loop over the table to check the row-state for no reason.

Comment: This _AcceptChanges_ is always source of confusion. I am curious to know what the OP thinks this methods does.

Comment: to jdweng : All DataTable obj have well their TableName (and unique). to Tim : Initially, I have had some problem with the state of my DataRowState ("added" instead "Unchanged") after using the SQLiteDataAdapter.fill() method. Maybe because I forgot to specify the TableName property of the DataTable, I didn't check it. So I would like to make a workaround by using the AcceptChanges() method to init all state of all row of all table to "unchanged" .

Comment: to Tim : Now, the row state is good and I can omit this line but I think that's very strange there is an exception when using it into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

WorkAround Solution : Swap these two lines

```
// Add row change event
table.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Table_RowChanged);

// Init lines status
table.AcceptChanges(); //-> throw an exception after several loops
```

AcceptChanges() can throw the RowChanged Event and in this case I have the exception.